# onNext from outside of observable

Tags: rxjs

I noticed I can't call onNext on a Observable object and pass the next value. The same thing can be achieved using a Subject object. I am wondering, is there a method with similar functionality as `onNext`, but you invoke it with a Observable object?

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
var subscibedToObservable = observable.subscribe(function(val){
console.log("val from observable: "+val);
});


var subject = new Rx.Subject();
    subject.subscribe(function(val){
    console.log("val from subject: "+val);
});

setInterval(function(){
    subject.onNext(12);
  observable.onNext(12); // does not exist

},1000);
```

Comment: No, that's what `Subject` is for.

Comment: okay. glad to get that out of the way.